# Putting inputs dynamically, avoid repeating on different elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding inputs dynamically, but once I try to add one input in an element, is adding the same input in a second hand element which is there due to a ng-repeat:

```
    <div ng-repeat="operation in operations">

            <p>{{operation.hola}}</p>

            <button class="btn" ng-click="addNewChoice([])">Add fields</button>                 

            <div data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
                <input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">                      
            </div>              

    </div>
```

controller

```
$scope.choices = [];
$scope.operations = [{
        hola: 'HELLO'
    }, {
        hola: 'BYE'
    }
    ];

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  $scope.choices.push(['']);
};
```

When you click on `Add Fields` button, it should be adding only one input in the proper box/form, and not in both boxes.

I did not explain myself very well but here I have a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fasune/1/edit?html,js,output) so you can check my issue.

Comment: you have to stop editing that jsbin so someone else can take a look :)

Comment: @sirrocco hahahaha yes, sorry. I just stop.

Comment: add the choices array to the operations array objects ... otherwise it's a common array and it won't work

Comment: @sirrocco I can not modify the json I am receiving. I am working with real data.

Comment: Added an answer - why couldn't you modify the json? Once it's on the client side .. you can do whatever to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you modify the json? It's in your program now - you can do whatever to it.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$scope.operations = [{hola: 'HELLO'}, {hola: 'BYE'}];

// this is JS - you have the power :)
// call this right after you get the json from your ajax call or something
$scope.operations = preProcessOperations($scope.operations);    


$scope.addNewChoice = function(choices) {
  choices.push(['']);
};

function preProcessOperations(ops){
  for(var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++){
    ops[i].choices = [];
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="operation in operations">
    <p>{{operation.hola}}</p>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="addNewChoice(operation.choices)">Add fields</button>     

    <div data-ng-repeat="choice in operation.choices track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">                      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: my first ng-repeat starts with ```operation in data.operations```, I am still trying.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. How are you getting your data ?

Answer (score 2):

Slight different way, you can try this too

```
   <div ng-repeat="operation in operations">            
        <div class="panel">             
            <div class="panel-body">                
              <p>{{operation.hola}}</p>                 
            <button class="btn" ng-click="addNewChoice(operation)">Add fields</button>
            <div data-ng-repeat="choice in choices[operation.hola] track by $index">
                <input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">                      
            </div>
          </div>                
        </div>          
    </div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ionicApp',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.choices = {};
    $scope.operations = [{
            hola: 'HELLO'
        }, {
            hola: 'BYE'
        }];

    $scope.addNewChoice = function(operation) {
      $scope.choices[operation.hola] = $scope.choices[operation.hola] || [];
      $scope.choices[operation.hola].push(['']);
    };    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/qufatesame/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `choices` to be different for each operation, then you need to create 2 different `choices` arrays. The best way is to create a `chioces` object on each operation:

```
$scope.operations = [{
    hola: 'HELLO',
    choices: []
}, {
    hola: 'BYE',
    choices: []
}];
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="operation in operations">
    <p>{{operation.hola}}</p>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="operation.choices.push([])">Add fields</button>     

    <div data-ng-repeat="choice in operation.choices track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">                      
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Edit:** if you don't want to modify your operations array for some reason, you can create a 2-dimensional ragged array for the choices:

```
$scope.operationChoices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < operations.length; ++i) {
    $scope.operationChoices.push([]);
}
```

Then your HTML would be:

```
<div ng-repeat="operation in operations" ng-init="choices = operationChoices[$index]">
    <p>{{operation.hola}}</p>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="choices.push([])">Add fields</button>     

    <div data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">                      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: nope, I am unable to add ```choices: []``` here my friend. you have to take into account that I am receiving a json that I can not modify, so the technic of adding that empty array there won't work this time.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: Why can't you modify the JSON after you receive it?

Comment: my first ng-repeat starts with ```operation in data.operations```, I am still struggling.

Comment: I don't understand... where does `data` come from?